# Where can I find the underlying math behind the ns() function in R?

Tags: r, references, splines

I am trying to come up with the B-spline basis matrix of natural cubic spline. I searched up and down the Internet and the only thing can find is the [ns() function in R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/splines/html/ns.html). The output is exactly what I want, but I would like to understand how this is done internally so that I can code similar things myself.

Comment: Read the associated reference? To see the function: `edit(ns)`.

Comment: There is no reference for ns()

Comment: Hastie, T. J. (1992) Generalized additive models. Chapter 7 of Statistical Models in S eds J. M. Chambers and T. J. Hastie, Wadsworth & Brooks/Cole.

Comment: ... as the "references" section of the help page says.

Comment: [An answer can probably be found somewhere here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=+natural+spline+answers%3A1).